# How to use App Pool Identity to connect using SqlClient in Powershell?

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, powershell

We have many servers with a ASP.Net application installed. I'm trying to figure out a automatic way to connect to the sql server using Powershell.

They use a domain account to run the app pool.  I have the code below to get the connection string from the app and the app pool identity to try to open a connection to sql.

However, when I run it in powershell, the sql login fails for, Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.  I don't understand why. I confirmed the ASP.Net Application is using the App Pool Identity in SQL via sp_who2.

Output confirms that the invoke-command is using the App Pool Identity.  I can't change the connectionstring per business policies.  I want to only use .Net to connect to SQL because I know .Net framework 4.8 will be on all machines I use to run it.

I removed the code for getting the connection string and app pool identity from the sample below in hopes to allow more people to troubleshoot.

Just update the username, password, and server name below and try it out

```
$username = 'MyUsername'
$password = 'MyPassword'        
 
$ConnStr = 'Data Source=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;'

$query = 'Select system_user, @@servername DBHostName,(SELECT login_time FROM sys.sysprocesses where spid=1)SQLUptime, @@version SQLVersion;'

$SQLPoshCmds = {
 $env:USERNAME
 $args[0]
    try{
      $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
      $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $args[0]

      $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
      $SqlCmd.CommandText = $args[1]
      $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
      $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
      $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
      $SqlConnection.open()
      $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
      $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
      $DataSet.Tables|fl

    }
    Catch{
      $_
      # write "`r`n$($_.Exception)"
      # write $_.ScriptStackTrace
      # write $_.ErrorDetails
    }
    Finally{
      $SqlConnection.Close()
      $SqlConnection.Dispose()
    }
}

if($ConnStr.Contains('Trusted_Connection=yes;')){
    invoke-command -ArgumentList $ConnStr,$query -ComputerName '.' -ScriptBlock $SQLPoshCmds -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force))
}else{
    invoke-command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock $SQLPoshCmds
}
```

Comment: Aside... you'll probably need to use `master.sys.sysprocesses` instead of `sys.sysprocesses`, depending on the default database specified on the connection (or the App Pool Identity user's default database if none is specified in the connection string). Also the user will need the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission to see any sessions other than their own.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `Invoke-Command` in your own Impersonation Context?

Comment: And would not the connection strings be in web config? I would certainly look at and check the connection strings in web config, since it's possible the code behind using a different connection then you are assuming

Comment: The running joke at my company whenever anyone sees "anonymous logon" is to yell "kerberos is broken". Of course it typically means double-hop is being denied because an SPN has not been registered (or more rarely, that delegation has been prohibited). I'm not a powershell person, but I notice your code has `ComputerName '.'` which would imply there is no double hop. But are you actually invoking on the local machine, or did you just put in the '.' to avoid any including any internal stuff in your SO question?

Comment: I think i'm going to try to replace trusted_connection=yes; with user id= and password= again.  The first time i tried, it i got error something like login is not a sql account.  Looking at some other code online, it seems i need to put 'Domain\user' instead of just 'user'   I didn't prefix it with Domain\

Comment: the period for computer name was to run it just like the asp.net app runs.  the powershell would run on the same web server that runs the app, typically connects to a remote sql server.

Comment: If you want to try with a SQL account, be aware that they have no connection with domain accounts. A domain user MyDomain\SomeUser does not automatically get a SQL Server authenticated login when their domain login is added to the Sql Server. It's a login that is created on the Sql Server, and known only to the Sql Server instance. A SQL Server authenticated login name cannot contain a backslash.

Comment: Replacing the credentials in the connection string didn't work either.  Now, I'm realizing this is even weirder cus the windows account I'm first executing the powershell with has admin access to sql too.  So even without the invoke-command, I would think it should run.  

I can connect in smss using win auth and have sysadmin level access.  But trying to open connection using sqlclient with trusted_connection fails,  login failed for anonymous user.

Comment: my admin user might be failing for not having spn registered.   I confirmed i can open powershell with run as user on the server desktop as the app pool identity windows account.  The sqlclient code works ok like that.   I tried using start-job but that fails for access denied.